# .NET MVC get current page and controller in shared layout

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, layout, view

I'm trying to fetch the current page from my shared layout in .net mvc app so that I can load a different favicon icon for the 2 different pages.

I've tried something like following:

```
@if (Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToString().ToLower().Contains("/Analyze/Index"))
{

    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png" />
}
```

But this doesn't works...

How can I fetch the current controller and view that user is on while browsing the website so that I can load this favicon in his/her browser?

Comment: Why don't you pass it as ViewData from controller so that you can have different favicon images for different contollers/actions.

Comment: @LKC ah good point as well ! =) Thx for the idea :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get your current controller name & action method name from your RouteData dictionary.

```
@{
    var controllerName = string.Empty;
    object controllerObj;
    var actionName = string.Empty;
    object actionObj;

    if (ViewContext.RouteData.Values.TryGetValue("controller", out controllerObj))
    {
        controllerName = controllerObj.ToString();
    }

    if (ViewContext.RouteData.Values.TryGetValue("action", out actionObj))
    {
        actionName = actionObj.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: so I should then just do: if controllername == "analyze" && actionname == "index" { // load here favicon ? }

Comment: @Shyju How to pass these controller and action name to other controller through on click of Html.ActionLink.. Note: ActionLink is in layout page. I want to pass current action and controller name through this ActionLink.

Answer (score 0):

I use something this to change my layout for some particular reasons with users that are not logged in or hasn't got claims yet.

Take consideration, Values will are keys where:

```
Value[0] = controller  
Value[1] = action
```

using this logic:

```
 if (ViewContext.RouteData.Values.Where(v => v.Key == "action").FirstOrDefault().Value.ToString() == "MyAction")
    {
        Layout = "_Layout_MyOtherLayout";
    }
    else
    {
        Layout = "_Layout";
    }
```