# Getting current user browsing controller and action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, path

I have a .NET app where I need to dynamically read from my shared view the current user path which he browses at the moment on website...

For example, if user is browsing:

mysite.com/Index/Index

I'd like to have this part of path read in my view:

```
/Index/Index
```

So that I can load different favicons to user depending on which page he is.

So it would look like something like this:

```
@if(currentPath == "/Index/Index")
{
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png" />
// loading defautl favicon
}
```

Is this doable in .NET view/razor ???

Comment: why not have the favicon path in your viewmodel and then just call it in the different views?

Comment: The way to handle this is to determine in the controller method (and if your apply this in multiple action methods, then use a `FilterAttribute`) and you can then pass the file name to the view (ideally as a view model property, but you could use `ViewBag`)

Comment: But if your really want to do it in the view, refer [these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852979/get-current-controller-in-view) (but ugly solutions)

Comment: How is this question different than your other question [.NET MVC get current page and controller in shared layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41782244/net-mvc-get-current-page-and-controller-in-shared-layout/41782328#41782328) ?